# Volley deliverResponse not being called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-volley

I am using Volley and I see the parseNetworkResponse
being called and all ok. The parsing is fine I can see in the logs
and I don’t return null.
But for some reason the deliverResponse is not being called? 
How could reason why this can happen or how I could debug this?

Even this:

```
@Override
        protected Response<Object> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
            Log.i(“TEST”, "Returning nothing from dummy parseNetworkResponse....");
            Response<Object> jsonResponse = Response.success(new Object(), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
            Log.i("TEST", "Returning nothing....");
            return jsonResponse;
        }
```

does not end up in calling the deliverResponse although I can see the logs in the LOGCAT

**UPDATE:**
I went through the debugger and I end up in the code in NetworkDispatcher (after network-parse-complete and post-response)
request.markDelivered();
mDelivery.postResponse(request, response);
Then the code in ExecutorDelivery.postResponse is executed:

```
mResponsePoster.execute(new ResponseDeliveryRunnable(request, response, runnable));
```

That would eventually call the mRequest.deliverResponse(mResponse.result);
but when I add a breakpoint in ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run the code does not break and so I assume that the runnable that would call the deliverResponse is not being run.
Any idea why this could happen?

Comment: show the related code. we dont know what you are doing.

Comment: Jim, what was you bug? I'm having the same issue as yours

Comment: @VitalyStakhov:For some reason the debugger does/did not break there. When I overriden the methods and added logs I saw the logs printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also look for errors in your `Network Response` and also notify Volley also rather than using Object, You also need to override `parseNetworkError, deliverResponse` methods. See my example (please don't be overwhelmed by so much boilerplate code)

```
public interface JsonParser_<T> {
        public T parseResponse_(JSONObject json);

        public T parseResponse_(JSONArray json);
    }



/**
     * 
     * @param tag
     *            : to tag your request with some string, so that you can cancel
     *            them any time
     * @param method
     *            <pre>
     * int DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST = -1;
     * int GET = 0;
     * int POST = 1;
     * int PUT = 2;
     * int DELETE = 3;
     * int HEAD = 4;
     * int OPTIONS = 5;
     * int TRACE = 6;
     * int PATCH = 7;
     * </pre>
     * @param url
     *            URL to hit
     * @param postParams
     *            Parameters that embeds with the URL itself
     * @param headerParams
     *            Parameters that goes inside header
     * @param jsonDelivery
     *            Listener will be called with JSON so that you can parse your
     *            JSON off the UI thread
     * @param resultDelivery
     *            It will return the resulf of delivery, very important to
     *            return the result in the first listener in parsing JSON
     * @param errorListener
     *            It anything goes wrong
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("hiding")
    protected final <T> void fetchAndParseResponse(final String tag,
            final int method, final String url,
            final Map<String, String> postParams,
            final Map<String, String> headerParams,
            final JsonParser_<T> jsonDelivery,
            final Response.Listener<T> resultDelivery,
            final Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

        AppContext.requestQueue.start();

        AppContext.requestQueue.add(new Request<T>(method, url,
                new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        setException(error);
                        if (errorListener != null)
                            // errorListener.onErrorResponse(wrapError(error));
                            errorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
                    }
                }) {

            @Override
            protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                T pojo = null;

                statusCode = response.statusCode;

                try {

                    String jsonString = new String(response.data, "UTF-8");
                    char char_ = new JSONTokener(jsonString).next();

                    if (char_ == '{') {

                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);

                        // isResponseOk(json);

                        pojo = jsonDelivery.parseResponse_(json);

                    } else {

                        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonString);
                        pojo = jsonDelivery.parseResponse_(json);

                    }

                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

                    setException(e);
                    // return Response.error(wrapError(new VolleyError(e)));
                    return Response.error((new VolleyError(e)));

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    setException(e);
                    // return Response.error(wrapError(new VolleyError(e)));
                    return Response.error((new VolleyError(e)));
                }

                return Response.success(pojo,
                        HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response, true));

            }

            @Override
            protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {
                if (volleyError.networkResponse != null
                        && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
                    VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(
                            volleyError.networkResponse.data));
                    volleyError = error;
                }

                return volleyError;
            }

            @Override
            protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
                if (resultDelivery != null)
                    resultDelivery.onResponse(response);
                else
                    VolleyLog.wtf("No listener attached with %s class", this
                            .getClass().getName());
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                if (headerParams == null) {
                    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
                    if (AppContext.userPojo != null) {
                        map.put("sid", AppContext.userPojo.SID);
                    }
                    return map;
                } else {
                    if (AppContext.userPojo != null) {
                        headerParams.put("sid", AppContext.userPojo.SID);
                    }
                }

                return headerParams;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                if (postParams == null)
                    return super.getParams();
                else
                    return postParams;
            }
        }.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy()).setTag(tag));

    }
```

Usage:

```
fetchAndParseResponse(tag, Method.POST, AZ_API.SOME_URL, null, null, new JsonParser_<StatusMessage>() {

            @Override
            public StatusMessage parseResponse_(JSONObject json) {

                requestStatus = parseStatus(json);
                message = parseMessage(json);

                StatusMessage msg = new StatusMessage();
                msg.setMessage(message);
                msg.setStatus(requestStatus);

                return msg;

            }

            @Override
            public StatusMessage parseResponse_(JSONArray json) {

                return null;
            }

        }, listener, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {                
                errorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I attached what I see in the debugger when I reach in ExecutorDelivery.postResponse which is supposed to schedule a ResponseDeliveryRunnable to call the `mRequest.deliverResponse(mResponse.result);` But it seems that that thread is never executed

Comment: See all the methods I have overridden, I am using Volley very very extensively in my project, I also wrote my custom Requests but it never happened even a single time as  your problem after overriding error methods. I have found Volley extremely stable. I would like to divert your attention again to my code snippet. Here is a Volley talk and demo https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mani.volleydemo

Comment: I have found a very subtle bug in my code that caused this. I am accepting your answer because overall I find your answer very helpful

Answer (score 4):

Check your volley logs for clues, as some of the above answerers mentioned. I use an alias to filter volley logs like so:

`alias vlog='adb shell setprop log.tag.Volley VERBOSE && adb logcat -Cv threadtime | grep -Ii '\''volley'\'''`

When I hit this exact issue, I noticed that the specific requests in question would show the following in the logs:

```
04-02 17:22:41.309 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [ 1] add-to-queue
04-02 17:22:41.309 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+10  ) [233] cache-queue-take
04-02 17:22:41.310 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [233] cache-miss
04-02 17:22:41.313 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+1   ) [234] network-queue-take
04-02 17:22:41.314 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+227 ) [234] network-http-complete
04-02 17:22:41.314 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+3   ) [234] network-parse-complete
04-02 17:22:41.315 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [234] post-response
04-02 17:22:41.315 21639 21639 D Volley  : [1] MarkerLog.finish: (+0   ) [ 1] canceled-at-delivery
```

Scroll to the right and you notice `[ 1] canceled-at-delivery` in that last line. This is printed by Volley if upon delivery it notices that the original request has been canceled via `cancel()`. I had an unfortunate code path that was doing this as a "cleanup action" prematurely leading the request being canceled prior to delivery causing Volley to discard it.

From [com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery:93](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/android-5.0.2_r1/src/com/android/volley/ExecutorDelivery.java):

```
    // If this request has canceled, finish it and don't deliver.
    if (mRequest.isCanceled()) {
        mRequest.finish("canceled-at-delivery");
        return;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I was doing parallel calls and then call cancelAll() your answer help me alot

Comment: Just got an upvote today... are people still using volley? 